# What is the methodology for selecting symbol bit length and window size when performing Shannon Entropy Analysis?

Tags: algorithm-design, random-number-generator, randomness, entropy, information-theory

When performing Shannon Entropy analysis on something like an RNG or a file, you must:

1. Select a symbol bit length and number of samples would will perform analysis on at a time (IE: windows size)
2. Read the input till the window is full
3. Perform a histogram on the collected symbols
4. Take the histogram output and calculate Shannon Entropy
5. Repeat step 2 by either getting entirely new samples or *sliding* the window (IE: keep a portion of the already used samples)

Tools like `binwalk` do this automatically under the hood and do a pretty good job at showing unusual portions of files; however, it is not entirely clear how they:

- Select symbol bit length
- Select the windows size
- If any window sliding is performed

Is there a methodology to selecting these values in the context of RNG and file analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liam, what you're asking is still an open question. There is no standardised methodology for calculating the entropy of a **file** in the general case. Even NIST have said so with their non IID 800-90B calculations. The following questions are rhetorical to illustrate the problem:-

1. What is the symbol bit length? Who knows. Shakespeare's works have line, act and paragraph demarcations. Are they included within your window? And they use weird words that could be represented by Huffman codes.
2. What do you histogram? Really, what exactly would you histogram?
3. How are the previous findings weighted?

The problem is not the window. It's the manipulation and weighting of said window that's the problem.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity, http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/technical/90b_latest/ and http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/technical/algorithms/ and follow the links.

In short, there is no such thing as Shannon Entropy analysis in the general case :-(

Comment: Well it is at least comforting I am not missing something obvious.

Comment: @LiamKelly God no. You're pushing boundaries of how we calculate entropy of general things. If you  followed the links, you'll  realise that it's quite tricky. The Shannon do-da formula only works or identically and independent sources.